# Speeding up small minibatches on a GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

Is it possible to use a smaller minibatch size and still fully utilize a large GPU?  My GPU can handle massive minibatch sizes (5000+) very quickly but with lower accuracy.  I’ve read about people sending smaller minibatch sizes to multiple GPU’s in parallel but I’m wondering if it is possible to send several smaller minibatch sizes to the same GPU in parallel.

So for example training 16 minibatches of 64 in parallel instead of training one 1024 minibatch at a time.  Or alternatively training 16 distinct models at the same time with small batches and aggregating the results.

Answer (score 0):

If you just using stander library like tensorflow, then this shouldn't be the type of problem you need to consider, it will try to utilize your GPU as much as possible at backend, if you get lower accuracy during training, try to find the problem in code and data  before looking at other way.

FWIW, you could try to optimize your GPU performance little more by following the guide of [tensorflow optimize performance on 1 GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu_performance_analysis#optimize_performance_on_1_gpu)

Comment: This is not really an answer, you are just speculating, and are unaware of issues with large batch sizes.

Comment: Maybe, hope you find what you need, have good day : )

Comment: Dr Snoopy is correct, I am trying to avoid large batch sizes due to issues with them converging on local optimums.  I think I have a valid and important question, why was it down voted.

Comment: @MichaelMalin Probably this question is too specific, not much people meet it before, maybe you could ask Dr. Snoopy directly.